# Configure AWS SNS with JMS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jms, amazon-sns, jms-topic

We have [Amazon SQS Java Messaging Library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib) as a wrapper for JMS around SQS. Similarly, we had to migrate our active mq *topic* services to AWS SNS. I was looking around for a similar approach. Is there a suitable API for it? I am already making use of SQS JMS library which works like a charm for us.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating your own library for this.  Amazon hasn't kept up with the JMS standards very well in the SQS library and you could customize this for your needs.  I would use the HTTP/HTTPS integration - see the [example code from Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.example.java.html) to show how to have a servlet be an SNS endpoint.

You could have a custom message that includes a JMS destination.  The servlet would parse the SNS message and then send the JMS message to the destination.